# How to connect nodes with without straight lines but 90 degrees and rounded corners?

Tags: tikz-arrows, nodes, node-connections

I want to connect some nodes but without straight lines but with 90 degree angle and to have it rounder. So far I have the following:

```
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.symbols,shapes.callouts,patterns}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[draw] (a0) {A0};
\node[draw, right=of a0] (b0) {B0};
\node[draw, below right=of b0] (c) {C};
\node[draw, right=of c] (d) {D};
\node[draw, below left=of c] (bn) {Bn};
\node[draw, left=of bn] (an) {An};

\draw[-latex, ->] ([yshift=5]a0.east) -- ([yshift=5]b0.west);
\draw[-latex, ->] ([yshift=2.5]a0.east) -- ([yshift=2.5]b0.west);
\draw[-latex, <-] ([yshift=-2.5]a0.east) -- ([yshift=-2.5]b0.west);
\draw[-latex, <-] ([yshift=-5]a0.east) -- ([yshift=-5]b0.west);

\draw[-latex, ->] ([yshift=5]an.east) -- ([yshift=5]bn.west);
\draw[-latex, ->] ([yshift=2.5]an.east) -- ([yshift=2.5]bn.west);
\draw[-latex, <-] ([yshift=-2.5]an.east) -- ([yshift=-2.5]bn.west);
\draw[-latex, <-] ([yshift=-5]an.east) -- ([yshift=-5]bn.west);

\draw[-latex, ->] ([yshift=2.5]b0.east) -| ([yshift=5]c.west);
\draw[-latex, <-] ([yshift=-2.5]b0.east) -| ([yshift=2.5]c.west);

\draw[-latex, ->] ([yshift=2.5]bn.east) -| ([yshift=-2.5]c.west);
\draw[-latex, <-] ([yshift=-2.5]bn.east) -| ([yshift=-5]c.west);

\draw[-latex, ->] ([yshift=2.5]c.east) -- ([yshift=2.5]d.west);
\draw[-latex, <-] ([yshift=-2.5]c.east) -- ([yshift=-2.5]d.west);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

Which looks like:

[image]

However, the lines from B0 to C to do the break downwards like now in the middle and then turn left to C, with rounded corners.

What should I add to each `\draw` line?

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add an auxiliary point at a certain distance from the starting node, then you can use `|-` argument. For the rounded corners, well... just add `rounded corners`.
Note that when you write `[-latex, ->]`, you overwrite your latex arrow with the common arrow, which is why it's better to define the arrow type into the `tikzpicture` declaration (see code below).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,positioning,shapes.symbols,shapes.callouts,patterns,fit}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
    
        \node[draw] (a0) {A0};
        \node[draw, right=of a0] (b0) {B0};
        \node[draw, below right=of b0] (c) {C};
        \node[draw, right=of c] (d) {D};
        \node[draw, below left=of c] (bn) {Bn};
        \node[draw, left=of bn] (an) {An};
        
        \draw[->] ([yshift=5]a0.east) -- ([yshift=5]b0.west);
        \draw[->] ([yshift=2.5]a0.east) -- ([yshift=2.5]b0.west);
        \draw[<-] ([yshift=-2.5]a0.east) -- ([yshift=-2.5]b0.west);
        \draw[<-] ([yshift=-5]a0.east) -- ([yshift=-5]b0.west);
        
        \draw[->] ([yshift=5]an.east) -- ([yshift=5]bn.west);
        \draw[->] ([yshift=2.5]an.east) -- ([yshift=2.5]bn.west);
        \draw[<-] ([yshift=-2.5]an.east) -- ([yshift=-2.5]bn.west);
        \draw[<-] ([yshift=-5]an.east) -- ([yshift=-5]bn.west);
        
        \draw[->,rounded corners=1pt] ([yshift=2.5]b0.east) --++ (.6,0) |- ([yshift=5]c.west);
        \draw[<-,rounded corners=1pt] ([yshift=-2.5]b0.east)--++ (.4,0) |- ([yshift=2.5]c.west);
        
        \draw[->,rounded corners=1pt] ([yshift=2.5]bn.east) --++ (.4,0) |- ([yshift=-2.5]c.west);
        \draw[<-,rounded corners=1pt] ([yshift=-2.5]bn.east) --++ (.6,0) |- ([yshift=-5]c.west);
        
        \draw[->] ([yshift=2.5]c.east) -- ([yshift=2.5]d.west);
        \draw[<-] ([yshift=-2.5]c.east) -- ([yshift=-2.5]d.west);

        \node[fit=(a0)(an)(d),draw,rounded corners=1pt]{}; % <-- This to add the bounding box around the nodes.
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

## EDIT

By request, I added a bounding box around the nodes, using `fit` library. Note that you have to load it in the preamble too.

[image: broken arrows and bounding box]

Comment: That looks great. Maybe a followup question....Then is it possible to draw a bounding box around all these nodes?

Comment: Asking another question in an answered topic is not usually an accepted behaviour, but, I'll edit my post, since it's no big deal.

Comment: I know. I should have edited the original question. Thanks a lot @SebGlav!